# is there any way to specify minimum cython version in a pyx file?

Tags: cython, cythonize

Some pyx files require advanced cython features. Some are not. Thus different pyx files have different minimum cython version requirement. Is there any mechanism that we can tell cythonize to throw an error if the version does not meet the requirement when it processing a pyx file?

We have many pyx files we would like to reuse. Use centralized way to manage the version requirement is clumsy obviously.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible right now. You might try filing an issue with a feature request on cython's github: https://github.com/cython/cython

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to generate the C files with Cython once, with an appropriate Cython version, then commit and reuse those C files for compilation *without* re-cythonizing.

That way, the version of Cython used is static and so are the resulting static C files which then do not need Cython installed.

Even with a minimum version specified, there is no guarantee that a later version of Cython will produce the same C code, or that the later version will work as expected.

[From documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=distributing#distributing-cython-modules):

> It is strongly recommended that you distribute the generated .c files as well as your Cython sources, so that users can install your module without needing to have Cython available.